# Convert SVG to PDF with iText, SVG is not fully displayed in PDF

Tags: java, svg, itext, itext7

I'm working on adding SVG image to PDF pages.

Firstly, I tried SvgConverter.createPDF to check if iText works with SVG.

Some svgs are fine.
Unfortunately, the following SVG (using percentage position) is not correctly displayed / positioned in PDF.

My Conversion code

```
    String svgImage = resourceFile("svg/circle-sRGB-rgb.svg");
    String destination = targetFile("svg-itext_SVG2PDF.pdf");

    try(InputStream svgStream = new FileInputStream(new File(svgImage))) {
        try(OutputStream pdfStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination))) {
            SvgConverter.createPdf(svgStream, pdfStream);
        }
    }
```

SVG file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 80 60">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" fill="rgb(10, 200, 200)"/>
</svg>
```

SVG Preview

[image]

Generated PDF Preview

[image]

If I change the position (cx, cy) in SVG to absolute values, output seems to be good.

I also tried converting the SVG to an xObject, but it also didn't help.

```
private void addSvgImageToPdfPage(PdfPage page, String svgContent, float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    // convert svg to xObject
    PdfFormXObject xObject = SvgConverter.convertToXObject(svgContent, page.getDocument());

    // create page canvas
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    // create AT
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
    at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(w / xObject.getWidth(), h / xObject.getHeight()));

    float[] matrix = new float[6];
    at.getMatrix(matrix);

    // add svg xObject to canvas
    pdfCanvas.addXObjectWithTransformationMatrix(xObject, matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3], matrix[4], matrix[5]);

    pdfCanvas.release();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @A.Alexander correctly mentioned, iText out of the box doesn't support relative parameters for the circle element.
However, you can register your own renderer for the circle tag (instead of CircleSvgNodeRenderer) that is able to deal with percents.

There is the parseAbsoluteLength method in AbstractSvgNodeRenderer which can be useful for that.

Custom renderer.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.svg.SvgConstants;

import com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.ISvgNodeRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.SvgDrawContext;
import com.itextpdf.svg.utils.DrawUtils;

/**
 * {@link ISvgNodeRenderer} implementation for the &lt;circle&gt; tag.
 */
public class CustomCircleSvgNodeRenderer extends AbstractSvgNodeRenderer {

    private float cx;
    private float cy;
    float r;

    @Override
    protected void doDraw(SvgDrawContext context) {
        PdfCanvas cv = context.getCurrentCanvas();
        cv.writeLiteral("% ellipse\n");
        if (setParameters(context)) {
            // Use double type locally to have better precision of the result after applying arithmetic operations
            cv.moveTo((double) cx + (double) r, cy);
            DrawUtils.arc((double) cx - (double) r, (double) cy - (double) r, (double) cx + (double) r,
                    (double) cy + (double) r, 0, 360, cv);
        }
    }


    private boolean setParameters(SvgDrawContext context) {
        cx = 0;
        cy = 0;
        if (getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CX) != null) {
            cx = parseAbsoluteLength(getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CX), context.getCurrentViewPort().getWidth(), 0.0f, context);
        }
        if (getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CY) != null) {
            cy = parseAbsoluteLength(getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CY), context.getCurrentViewPort().getHeight(), 0.0f, context);
        }
        if (getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.R) != null
                && parseAbsoluteLength(getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CY), context.getCurrentViewPort().getHeight(), 0.0f, context) > 0) {
            r = parseAbsoluteLength(getAttribute(SvgConstants.Attributes.CY), context.getCurrentViewPort().getHeight(), 0.0f, context);
        } else {
            return false; //No drawing if rx is absent
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ISvgNodeRenderer createDeepCopy() {
        CustomCircleSvgNodeRenderer copy = new CustomCircleSvgNodeRenderer();
        deepCopyAttributesAndStyles(copy);
        return copy;
    }

}
```

**Then you need to customize DefaultSvgNodeRendererFactory**.

New Factory must create instance of CustomCircleSvgNodeRenderer every time SvgConverter renders a circle.
e.g

```
public class CustomRendererFactory extends DefaultSvgNodeRendererFactory {

    @Override
    public ISvgNodeRenderer createSvgNodeRendererForTag(IElementNode tag, ISvgNodeRenderer parent) {
        if (SvgConstants.Tags.CIRCLE.equals(tag.name())) {
            return new CustomCircleSvgNodeRenderer();
        }
        return super.createSvgNodeRendererForTag(tag, parent);
    }
}
```

**Enforce SVGConverter to use CustomRendererFactory**

You should add this factory to ConverterProperties instance and then use methods from SvgConverter that have a parameter of type ISvgConverterProperties.

```
    SvgConverterProperties properties = new SvgConverterProperties();
    properties.setRendererFactory(new RendererFactory());
    // xObject
    SvgConverter.convertToXObject(svg, pdfDoc, properties);
    // or pdf
    SvgConverter.createPdf(svgStream, pdfStream, properties);
```

Comment: Thank Pavel. It almost done. except that tag comparison should apply to `tag.name()`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the circle contains percents in cx and cy attributes.
EllipseSvgNodeRenderer class from itextpdf lib does not support percents, only pixels.

https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7J/repos/itextcore/browse/svg/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/svg/renderers/impl/EllipseSvgNodeRenderer.java#64

So when you run your code the following error appears in the console:

```
ERROR [main] CssUtils - Unknown absolute metric length parsed "%".
```

The "%" symbol is ignored and instead of 40 and 30 pixels cx and cy get 50px
values both.

Comment: You linked to an incorrect class.  CircleSvgNodeRenderer does handle the <circle> tag.

Comment: You can debug code in question and see that EllipseSvgNodeRenderer does it.

Comment: It seems related. But removing the '%' in svg, the generated PDF is different with the file with % in cx and cy.

Comment: sure. as % sign defines these values are relative and must be calculated depending on the parent`s size.
Without%, these are absolute values in pixels.

Comment: to be precise, @A.Alexander the error is thrown in the setParameter method which is overridden in CircleSvgNodeRenderer